# WCF open to internet users

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, authentication, iis

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS and here is the web config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFactoryData" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWatheq">        
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IFactoryData" />
  </netTcpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="allowMax" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
        </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://eind.mci.gov.sa/FactoryWCF/FactoryData.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFactoryData" contract="MCI_FactoryData.IFactoryData" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFactoryData" />
  <endpoint address="https://wathiqprep.thiqah.sa/2.0/Wathiq.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWatheq" contract="WatheqServiceRef.IWatheq" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWatheq" />
  <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://mci-inddb.mci.gov/FactoryWCF/FactoryData.svc"
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IFactoryData"
    contract="MCI_FactoryData.IFactoryData" name="NetTcpBinding_IFactoryData">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/MCI-INDDB.MCI.GOV" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>-->
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Web" />
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mex">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mex" name="SIDFService.FactoryService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="allowMax" contract="SIDFService.IFactoryService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mex" name="SIDFService.WatheqService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="allowMax" contract="SIDFService.IWatheqService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mex" name="SIDFService.TempIndustrialLicenseService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="allowMax" contract="SIDFService.ITempIndustrialLicenseService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mex" name="SIDFService.SaudiPostAddressService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="allowMax" contract="SIDFService.ISaudiPostAddressService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The setting on IIS is anonymous is enabled and Windows is enabled ... the service wsdl is accessble outside the domain but on WCF test client it is asking for windows credentials. The same when windows is disabled on IIS authentication, the service gives error on browser outside domain.

Comment: Okay... What's your question here???

Comment: I need settings where I can expose the WCF service to internet users

Comment: Then disable anonymous settings from IIS and try...

Comment: disabling anonymous setting on IIS and enabling windows or disable both?

Comment: If you want to all the users to access your service Use anonymous settings and disable windows authentication..